# Testing Method stuck at 25%

Tags: code-coverage

Here is the controller

```
public with sharing class QuoteClone {
    public Opportunity opp { get; set; }

    public QuoteClone() {
        opp = new Opportunity();
    }
    public pagereference savedata() {
        PageReference ref = null;

        if(opp.SyncedQuoteId==null) {
            opp.SyncedQuoteId.addError('You must select a quote.');
        }
        if(opp.AccountId==null) {
            opp.AccountId.addError('You must select an account.');
        }
        if(opp.SyncedQuoteId!=null && opp.AccountId != null) {
            Set<String> QuoteFields = schema.Quote.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset(),
                        OppFields = schema.opportunity.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset(),
                        QuoteLineFields = schema.quotelineitem.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset();
            Quote q = (Quote)Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(quotefields),',')+' from quote where id = \''+opp.syncedquoteid+'\'');
            Opportunity o = (Opportunity)Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(oppfields),',')+' from opportunity where id = \''+q.opportunityid+'\'');
            o = o.clone(false,false,false,false);
            q = q.clone(false,false,false,false);
            o.accountid = opp.accountid;

            //clear some oppty info before clone
            o.stageName = 'New';
            o.Amount = 0;
            o.Name = opp.Name;
            o.Probability = 0;
            o.SyncedQuoteId = NULL;

            insert o;
            q.opportunityid = o.id;


            //clear some qte info before clone
            q.status = 'Needs Approval - Please Submit Below';
            q.name = opp.Name;
            q.BillingName = NULL;
            q.BillingStreet = NULL;
            q.BillingCity = NULL;
            q.BillingPostalCode = NULL;
            q.ShippingName = NULL;
            q.ShippingStreet = NULL;
            q.ShippingCity = NULL;
            q.ShippingPostalCode = NULL;

            insert q;
            QuoteLineItem[] items = (QuoteLineItem[])Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(quotelinefields),',')+' from quotelineitem where quoteid = \''+opp.syncedquoteid+'\'');
            items = items.deepClone(false,false,false);
            for(QuoteLineItem item:items) {
                item.quoteid = q.id;
            }
            insert items;
            ref = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(q).view();
        }
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Here is the test...Nothing in `if(opp.SyncedQuoteId!=null && opp.AccountId != null)` is being tested and I can't figure out how to get there. Here is my testing code...keep in mind I've tried about 100 different things and I know I'm missing something obvious.

```
@isTest
public class TestQuoteClone 
{
    public static testMethod void TestMyQuoteClone()
    {
        //get user from account
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Isactive=TRUE LIMIT 1];

        //create Territory record
        Territory__c t = new Territory__c(Name ='TESTTerritory', X3_Digit_Zip__c = '605', Region__c = 'Midwest', Country__c = 'USA', 
                                          State__c = 'VT', Sales_Rep__c = u.Id);
        System.debug('territory Owner: ' + t.Sales_Rep__c+ ' ' + t.Sales_Rep__r.Name);
        insert t;    

        //create account as distributor
        Account a = new Account(Name    ='Test Account', Account_ID__c = 'TESTED', Type = 'End User', 
                                      Industry = 'Dental (GP)', BillingStreet = '1800 Test', BillingCity = 'Test', 
                                      BillingStateCode = 'VT', BillingPostalCode = '60543', BillingCountryCode = 'US');
        insert a;

        //create Opportunity
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name ='Test Opportunity', AccountId = a.Id, CloseDate = date.newInstance(2018,01,01), StageName = 'New');
        insert o;

        //create quote
        Quote qte = new Quote(Name = 'Test Quote', OpportunityId = o.Id);
        insert qte;

         // Set page
        pagereference pageRef = Page.Clone_Quote_to_New_Opportunity;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        // Instantiate Controller
        QuoteClone controller = new QuoteClone();
        PageReference nextPage = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(qte).view();

        // Verify that page fails without parameters
        //System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);

        // Populate Deal Name
        //controller.opp.Name = 'TEST1234';

        System.assertEquals(a.id,o.AccountId);
        controller.savedata();




        Quote[] quotes = [select id,status,BillingName,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingPostalCode,ShippingName,ShippingStreet,ShippingCity,ShippingPostalCode, name from quote where name = 'Test Quote'];
        Opportunity[] oppty = [select id, AccountId FROM opportunity WHERE ID=:o.Id];

        System.assertEquals(a.id,o.AccountId);
        System.assertEquals(qte.id, quotes[0].id);
        System.assertNotEquals(NULL, a.Id);
        System.assertNotEquals(NULL, qte.Id);

       //System.assertEquals(o.Id, oppty[0].Id);
       //System.assertEquals(controller.opp, o);
       // System.assertEquals(qte.BillingName, quotes[0].BillingName);
       // System.assertEquals(qte.BillingStreet, quotes[0].BillingStreet);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].BillingCity);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].BillingPostalCode);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].ShippingName);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].ShippingStreet);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].ShippingCity);
       // System.assertEquals(NULL, quotes[0].ShippingPostalCode);
       //System.assertEquals(controller.opp.Name, quotes[0].name);
       // Verify that the success page displays
        System.assertNotEquals(pageRef,nextPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not mocking Opportunities with a value in `opp.SyncedQuoteId` ?

Comment: Thanks cropredy - I now have it synced but no luck

Comment: this is a custom controller rather than a custom `controller extension`. Is that intended?  The answer to this will guide  me in answering this question

Comment: Yes it only applies to 1 particular situation so it is a custom controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start here:

The test class instantiates the controller as follows:

```
QuoteClone controller = new QuoteClone();
```

The test class then tests the method `saveData` as follows:

```
controller.savedata();
```

But, if we look at custom (not extension) controller code, there is no code at all to fetch an Opportunity (?!?)

```
public with sharing class QuoteClone {
public Opportunity opp { get; set; }

public QuoteClone() {
    opp = new Opportunity();  // this instantiates an empty sobject
}
public pagereference savedata() {
    PageReference ref = null;
    ...
    return ref;
}
```

Now, since I can't see the VF page, it isn't clear to me how a real Opportunity is ever made known to the controller but for argument's sake, let's say it is done through the setter on `opp` (Of course, normally this would be done by passing an ID URL parameter and fetching the Opportunity in the controller)

Thus your test code needs to do the following with at least three mocked Opportunities

```
QuoteClone controller = new QuoteClone();
controller.opp = new Opportunity(SyncedQuoteId =null)
controller.savedata();
// do asserts here to verify expected vs actual results


QuoteClone controller = new QuoteClone();
controller.opp = new Opportunity(SyncedQuoteId = '0Q0000000000001');
controller.savedata();
// do asserts here to verify expected vs actual results


QuoteClone controller = new QuoteClone();
controller.opp = someMockedOppoWhoseSyncedQuoteIdIsNonNull;
controller.savedata();
// do asserts here to verify expected vs actual results
```